# Replicated MongoDB + spring-data-mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

There is a replicated mongodb (mongodb-1 - primary, mongodb-2 - secondary, mongodb-3 - secondary).
The app runs through spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb.

Service:

```
public class FooBarService {
  private FooBarRepository repository;

  public FooBar method1() {
    return repository.someQuery();
  }
  
  public FooBar method2() {
    return repository.someQuery();
  }
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface FooBarRepository extends MongoRepository<FooBar, String> {
  FooBar someQuery();
}
```

My question is, how nice to make it so that method1 reads from the primary participant in the mongo replica set, and method2 reads from the secondary participant in the mongo replica set?

Would like to find some way to manage this at the service level (Something like @Transactional, but to select a mongo replica set member).

Can you advise me on any solutions in this regard?

Answer (score 3):

### Solution 1: `@Meta` Annotation

If you want to continue using Repository Interfaces, you can annotate the query method definition with the `@Meta` annotation which lets you pass flags to indicate to read from a secondary mongodb member.

```
public interface FooBarRepository extends MongoRepository<FooBar, String> {

  @Query("{}")
  @Meta(flags = Meta.CursorOption.SECONDARY_READS)
  FooBar someQuery();
}
```

But you cannot control this flag from the service level. You would have to create 2 query methods: One with the flag and one without it. Like `someQueryFromSecondary()` and `someQueryFromPrimary()`.

### Solution 2: Using `MongoTemplate`

Another option would be to use `MongoTemplate` directly and set the flag on the `Query`.

```
public void someQuery(boolean readFromSecondary) {
    var query = Query.query(Criteria.where("someKey").is("1"));

    if (readFromSecondary) {
        query.allowSecondaryReads();
    }

    return mongoTemplate.findOne(query, FooBar.class);
}
```

Regardless which solution you choose: be aware of that reading from secondary members can lead to retrieving stale data. [Consider taking a look at the mongodb docs.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/)

Comment: Yes, I also knew only these solutions, but they look either too confusing, like Meta, or cumbersome like MongoTemplate. Perhaps you can suggest how you could wrap the MongoTemplate so that it works from the service level? Possibly with AOP. Something like @Transactional I guess

Comment: No this is not supported and i do not think that this use case will ever be supported by spring-data-mongodb. It would also be quite hard to implement it yourself. In my opinion this belongs completely to the repository and should not be controlled by the service layer. Maybe you could explain your use case a bit more to get some context.

Comment: In my application, secondary reading error is not important, but for some of the methods, it is. The repository methods call me from both types, so it's problematic to use the secondary layer for this. A MongoTemplate could be used, but that would complicate the application logic a lot. I would just like to find a way to manage this process without affecting the main code with business logic. Perhaps even an independent implementation of a solution, but in order to do it yourself, you need to understand which side to approach this.

Comment: Ok. So if you really want to come up with a solution at any application layer (controller, service ...) and want to do it the @Transactional way you would have to create a custom annotation, intercept the target methods with for example spring-aop and store the information about the read preference in some context/thread-local. Create a custom MongoTemplate which inherits the default spring MongoTemplate, override the executeQuery method and set the flag if in the context. But all of this will produce side-effects if not implemented correctly. I would not go with this solution